# How to read xml into class?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I want to deserialize xml into c#.
But I am getting error and cannot fix it.

Error is:

```
 "There is an error in XML document (1, 2)." 
 ...
 "<A xmlns=''> was not expected."
```

Deserialize code:

```
    public static object XmlDeserializeFromString(string objectData, Type type)
    {
        var xmlAttributes = new XmlAttributes();
        var xmlAttributeOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

        xmlAttributes.Xmlns = false;
        xmlAttributeOverrides.Add(typeof(A10), xmlAttributes);


        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type, xmlAttributeOverrides);
        object result=null;

        try
        {
            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(objectData))
            {
                result = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The class is:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(TypeName = "A-1.0", Namespace = "")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("A", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]  
public  class A10
{

    private string versField;

    private string typeField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string type
    {
        get
        {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And testing by:

```
   string xml = "<A vers=\"1.0\" type=\"pd\">";

   A10 a = (A10) XmlDeserializeFromString(xml, typeof(A10));
```

The exception is thrown on line:

```
 result = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Why this is happening? How to solve this?

Comment: Can you include a snippet of your XML?

Comment: <A vers="1.0" type="pd">

Comment: have you tried using only [System.Serializable()] above your class ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. The error is still showing.

Comment: As an additional point, unless you're *really* performance limited I would reccomend using the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace for parsing XML. It comes with `XDocument`, `XElement`, and `XAttribute`. Each of which are generally considered to be easier to use when parsing XML.

Comment: When I change XmlSerializer(type, xmlAttributeOverrides) to XmlSerializer(type) deserialization is going fine. What is going on?

Answer (score 4):

`<A vers="1.0" type="pd">` is not XML. See the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed). Your root element is missing its closing tag.

Make your document look like this:

```
<A vers="1.0" type="pd"></A>
```